# Solve for $x$ - Logarithm Equation $\ln x+\ln(x+1)=\ln 2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

My attempt:

$\ln x(x+1)=\ln 2$

$e^{\ln x(x+1)}=e^{\ln 2}$

$x(x+1)=2$

$x^2+x-2=0$

$(x-1)(x+2)=0$

therefore $x=1, -2$

Comment: Several errors in the development. Did you cheat ?

Comment: The equation is not defined for $x=-2$ since $\ln(x)$ only exists for $x>0$. Therefore $x=1$ is the only valid solution

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Just to check, you could just [look at the graph](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=real+part+of+Log[x]%2BLog[x%2B1]-Log[2]) on the web.

Comment: @NikolajK: won't this let the OP believe that $-2$ is acceptable, which I doubt ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust: Yes, I guess one should drop the "real part" to see the complex one too ([here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Log[x]%2BLog[x%2B1]-Log[2])). I don't know OPs background and left it to him to argue $x>0$. The wolframalpha page explicitly tells you the root too, though.

Comment: @NikolajK: I would have preferred $\ln(z)+\ln(z+1)=\ln(2)$ ;-)

Answer (score 3):

$$\ln { x+\ln { \left( x+1 \right) =\ln { 2 }  }  } \\ \ln { x\left( x+1 \right) =\ln { 2 }  } \\ x\left( x+1 \right) =2\\ x^{ 2 }+x-2=0\\ \left( x-1 \right) \left( x+2 \right) =0\\ { x }_{ 1 }=-2,{ x }_{ 2 }=1\\ $$
x should be $x>0$ hence ${ x }_{ 2 }=1$ is root

Answer (score 2):

By inspection, $x=1$ is a solution. As the logarithm function is strictly increasing, it is the only one.

Comment: ...however $x(x+1)$ isn't ...

Comment: Yes but I think that your answer should probably address that point.

Comment: @JpMcCarthy: I prefer to leave it so. You see a product $x(x+1)$ that does not appear in the original equation $\ln(x)+\ln(x+1)$. Please don't tell me that this equals $\ln(x(x+1))$, it isn't true.

Comment: -1 removed but I still think the other answers are better considering the difficulties that the OP is having... I can't remove it at the moment.

Comment: @JpMcCarthy: for complete completeness, I should have said, both $\ln(x)$ and $\ln(x+1)$ are strictly increasing functions so that their sum is a strictly increasing function as well; I left this implicit, shame on me. My solutions avoids modifying the original formula in any way, such as by taking the antilogarithm, and this is on purpose.

Answer (score 1):

$\ln x+\ln (x+1)=\ln 2$

$e^{\ln x+\ln (x+1)}=e^{\ln 2}$

$e^{\ln x}. e^{\ln x+1}=2$

$x.(x+1)=2$

Now we have a quadratic equation

Answer (score 0):

We have, $$\ln x+\ln x(x+1)=\ln 2$$ $$\implies \ln(x(x+1))=\ln 2$$
$$\implies \frac{\ln(x(x+1))}{\ln 2}=1$$ $$\implies \log_2(x(x+1))=1$$ $$\implies x(x+1)=2$$ $$\implies x^2+x-2=0$$ now, solving above quadratic equation for $x$ as follows $$\implies x=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{(1)^2-4(1)(-2)}}{2(1)}$$   $$\implies x=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{9}}{2}$$   $$\implies x=\frac{-1\pm 3}{2}$$ $$\implies x=\frac{-1+3}{2}=\color{}{1}$$ &$$\implies x=\frac{-1-3}{2}=\color{}{-2}$$
**Edit**: Since log is defined for positive number i.e. $x>0$ hence we have $x=\color{blue}{1}$

Comment: $-2$ is not a solution... -1

Comment: Oh, sorry, you are right. I could not check for negative value.